# Is it possible to make formula for 'ratio of conversion in RPG game'?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm developing RPG(Role-Playing Game) game and I'm planning make a formula for 'How much damage is being converted'.

I'm not previliged to put embedded images, but I hope you **check out the image here**(It will  make my question clear) >>
[image about my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUtmh.jpg)

- each '<---->' line is the *duration* of damage
- The blue-highlighted part means the part of damage that is converted
- The blue number next to '<---->' line means the ratio of damage converted.

First, let me get my keywords clear.

> Duration

'*Duration*' means 'The time it takes for all damage to be applied'. In my game, character's damage isn't applied instantly. For example if character does 100 damage and the *duration* of damage is 5 second, the damage will be applied like 20(1s), 20(2s), 20(3s), 20(4s), 20(5s). As a result, it takes as much time as '*duration*' before all damage is applied.

> Conversion

'*Conversion*' is my game's system which changes the type of damage(ex. fire -> water).
*Conversion* doesn't affect the damage that is already applied. It only affects the remaining damage. For example if *conversion* happens at 3s in example for '*Duration*', damage applied in 1s, 2s is not affected by *conversion*, and only remaining 60(at 3s, 4s, 5s) will be affected.

> Cooldown (of conversion)

'*Cooldown*' means 'The time it takes for the next *conversion* to take place'. For example, if *cooldown* is 5s, the *conversion* will happen 0s, 5s, 10s, ... and so on.

**My main question is this : Can I calculate average ratio of damage being converted from knowing *duration* and *cooldown*?**

As you can see in the image, I tried to calculate average ratio of 2 cases. Case1 with 3s *duration* and 4s *cooldown* and Case2 with 4s *duration* and 3s *cooldown*.

In the image I set minimum time unit to 1s since I'm dealing with average, the result would be equal regardless of minimum time unit.

I found out that average ratio of *conversion* is proportional to *duration*, and is inversely proportional to *cooldown*. However I couldn't go any further. Please let me know if you have any good idea.